# Python RegEx to look for a combination (not an arrangement) of given words: Is it possible?

Tags: python, regex

I want to have a regex in Python that matches a set of **exactly** and **only** these words separated by any number of spaces: Alex, Ben, Carol, David. Given these examples (every line is a separate test string):

```
Alex Ben Carol David
David Alex Carol Ben
Carol   David    Ben  Alex
Alex Ben Carlos Dave
Anthony Ben Carol Dave
Alex Carol David
Ben
```

The first 3 test string matches whole string, while the others don't have any matches. Is it possible using only regex? If not, how do I combine it with Python?

I tried changing Ωmega's answer on my previous question like so: `^(?=.*Alex)(?=.*Ben)(?=.*Carol)(?=.*David)(?:.*(?:$|\s+)){4}$` but that didn't work out very well.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^(?:Alex|Ben|Carol|David|Anthony|Carlos|Dve)(?:\s+(?:Alex|Ben|Carol|David|Anthony|Carlos|Dave))*$` https://regex101.com/r/dNBt0W/1

Comment: Why are you doing this with regex? You could split the lines on spaces and do a set comparison, for example.

Comment: No not that regex101.com/r/dNBt0W/1, as I said above: Each line is a separate test string.

Comment: @jonrsharpe because I want to combine it with other regex-es.

Comment: Could you provide more context in the question? Maybe those other regex shouldn't be regex either.

Comment: Try `^(?!.*\b(\w+)\b.*\b\1\b)(?:Alex|Ben|Carol|David|Anthony|Carlos|Dave)(?:\s+(?:Alex|Ben|Carol|David|Anthony|Carlos|Dave))*$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/R2Azgv/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible, yes, exceedingly pretty, no. You could chain several lookahead assertions that independently check whether their word is in the line and then match the whole line if none of them threw false:

```regex
^(?=.*\bAlex\b)(?=.*\bBen\b)(?=.*\bCarol\b)(?=.*\bDavid\b).*$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S9udtf/1).

Update to meet the specific requirement that **only** the listed words may be present in the line:

```regex
/
^
# Make sure the line only consists of targeted words.
(?=
    # First word.
    (?:Alex|Ben|Carol|David)
    # Three more words until the end of line.
    (?:[ \t]+(?:Alex|Ben|Carol|David)){3}$
)
# Make sure all four required words are present.
(?=.*\bAlex\b)(?=.*\bBen\b)(?=.*\bCarol\b)(?=.*\bDavid\b)
# Now match the line if all assertions were true.
.*
$
/x
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S9udtf/2).

Splitting the line and then comparing via string functions or dictionaries would probably be the more performant approach.

Comment: The problem with your regex is that "Alex a Ben Carol David" matches too

Comment: @TrietVoNguyenMinh It wasn't apparent to me in your question that a line may *only* consist of the targeted words. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a brutal simple solution by grouping all your possibilities in a selection: `(Alex|Ben|Carol|David)*\s*`

try it out here: https://regex101.com/r/MDoAgW/2

i am unsure as to what your exact question is though. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your expression also matches the empty string and a concatenation of names (which, to be fair, is not excluded by the wording of 'any number of spaces' but seems to be not the intent of the OP) because you quantify both parts with `*` (i.e. zero or more) and you use a capturing group `(...)` where you don't need to capture. Also, you match only single words right now, not a whole line of words.